# Deploy core functions of Unity as web services?

Tags: web-services, unity-game-engine, restful-architecture

By core functions I mean like rendering, physics engine, scripting etc. Basically distribute the Unity engine over the network, while each of them can communicate with each other via HTTP requests.

I would imagine that to do so, one would have to access the source code of Unity engine? But since it's not open-source, would Unreal Engine be a better bet?

Any info will be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather vague, but in theory of course you can make any functionality available to the web that is available to your code.

You'd write a Mediator that takes requests from the web, translates them into specific tasks and forwards them to the Unity engine, using Unity's API. Once Unity has finished processing the tasks, the results are collected by your Mediator and sent as a response to the initial request.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! That's sort of what I had in mind, but I'm having trouble figuring out whom to pass the translated tasks to, should it be a function in the Unity script or plugin, and the function itself calls a Unity api? And one other thing: it's not possible to make the Mediator a plugin, and thus make a whole Unity app handle requests within its own?